# I don't want to close my app in Android?

Tags: android

When I run my application, it is running as it is,
but i don't want to close main screen.
When any person want to close that activity than no one can close that application
Means in short, Once my app start, no one can interact other application
It is possible in android?

Please give me ans.

Thanks,

Pintu

Answer (score 3):

Short of rooting the device and drastically re-writing the operating system, no, you cannot make it impossible for someone to switch tasks. The hardware task-switcher is built into most Android devices.

More importantly, you **should** not. Android users rely on their devices remaining functional. While it's tempting to imagine using Android as a simple basis for integrated device development, it has always been intended as a multi-application platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this to some extent by considering how an application actually is closed. It is either when the user presses the back key or the home key. You can, in your main activity, override these event listeners and act upon them accordingly. This code show how to catch the back key press:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        // Your code here
   }

}
```

There are of course way to exit your application anyway. But there also methods to bring it to front again (for example running a background service and firing intents from there when you app is no longer in front).

Just remember this is far from common practise and should absolutely not be used in an app you plan on placing on the Android Market.